# Playing custom notification sound using Cloud Functions - iOS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm sending notification to my client app using `Cloud Functions` and `GoogleCloudMessaging` in this way:

```
const notificationContent = {
          notification: {
            title: `${senderName} has sent you a message`,
            body: `${messageString}`,
            icon: "default",
            sound: "customNotificationSound",
          },
        };
        return admin.messaging()
            .sendToDevice(notifToken, notificationContent)
            .then((result) =>{
              console.log("write done correctly");
            });
```

I want to use a custom notification sound instead of the default one; so I followed some guides online like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support), [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1) and [this](https://medium.com/@prakash.maharjan/play-custom-push-notification-sound-ios-a767748a46) but they don't seem to answer my question.

Since I'm sending the push notification from the cloud function, do I still need to load the sound file in the client Main Bundle (I tried it and in fact it doesn't seem to work).

Or do I have to upload it somewhere else?

P.s. also the sound file extension is .wav so there shouldn't be problems for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this and the answer is Yes, you still need to upload the `music file` in your `main bundle` even tough you're sending the push notification from cloud functions